# PostgreSQL - Flatten nested JSONB object array

Tags: postgresql, json

Im my database with Postgres 11, i have this [JSON](https://pastebin.com/E1uW9VLT) in my rows stored in a JSONB field, and i need to flatten out the list of objects that are over "ports" key, so, instead of having a json output i need to have them in a "flattended table" way like below

```
port_name, port_description, port_status_int, port_status, port_speed_int, ports_speed
...
"GigabitEthernet0/0", "", 2, "Not Connect", 1000000000, "1G"
"Bluetooth0/4", "", 2, "Not Connect", 1000000000, "1G"
...
```

Note that the lenght of the "ports" object is not static and may vary.

As far i know, this it my solution...i have some doubts: is this solution ok? it can be a bottleneck? it can be optimized?

```
SELECT  mytable.measurement_id,
(jsonb_array_elements(mytable.data->'ports')::jsonb)->'port_name' as "port_name",
(jsonb_array_elements(mytable.data->'ports')::jsonb)->'port_description' as "port_description",
(jsonb_array_elements(mytable.data->'ports')::jsonb)->'port_status_int' as "port_status_int",
(jsonb_array_elements(mytable.data->'ports')::jsonb)->'port_status' as "port_status",
(jsonb_array_elements(mytable.data->'ports')::jsonb)->'port_speed_int' as "port_speed_int",
(jsonb_array_elements(mytable.data->'ports')::jsonb)->'ports_speed' as "ports_speed"
from mytable where device_id = 20;
```

Any toughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set returning functions should be called in the FROM.

```
SELECT mt.measurement_id,
       p.port ->> 'port_name' as "port_name",
       p.port ->> 'port_description' as "port_description",
       p.port ->> 'port_status_int' as "port_status_int",
       p.port ->> 'port_status' as "port_status",
       p.port ->> 'port_speed_int' as "port_speed_int",
       p.port ->> 'ports_speed' as "ports_speed"
from mytable mt 
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(mt.data->'ports') as p(port)
where device_id = 20;
```

You can simplify this a bit, by using `jsonb_to_recordset`:

```
SELECT  mt.measurement_id,
        p.*
from mytable mt 
  cross join jsonb_to_recordset(mt.data->'ports') as p(port_name text, port_description text, port_status_int int, port_status text, port_speed_int int, ports_speed text) 
where device_id = 20;
```

Comment: The second solution, using the jsonb_to_recordset method is simple but impressive! the only question i have is about this notation: p.* - what does this mean?

Comment: `p` is the [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) for the result of `jsonb_to_recordset()`. `p.*` simply selects all columns from that "table"