# Cross join flatten JSON - flatten only one the most recent row

Tags: postgresql, json

As reported in this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/274909/postgresql-flatten-nested-jsonb-object-array), i want to flatten a JSON starting from a nested JSON object that contains arrays like this one:

```
port_name, port_description, port_status_int, port_status, port_speed_int, ports_speed
...
"GigabitEthernet0/0", "", 2, "Not Connect", 1000000000, "1G"
"Bluetooth0/4", "", 2, "Not Connect", 1000000000, "1G"
...
```

It works, but it flattens all rows that were returned from the query: i need only to flatten the objects that are contained into the first, most recent row (ordered by insert time desc), but when in my clause i'll insert `LIMIT 1` it will return only the first flattened json row, why? maybe this is a beginner question, but i'm not able to figure out!

This is the my actual query:

```
SELECT  mt.measurement_id,
        p.*
from mytable mt 
  cross join jsonb_to_recordset(mt.data->'ports') as p(port_name text, port_description text, port_status_int int, port_status text, port_speed_int int, ports_speed text) 
where device_id = 20;
```

Comment: It is the insert time column at row level: there is a pk - insert_time - data (json). sorry, i've missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (haven't tried it)

```
with my_mt as (
  select * from mytable
     where device_id = 20
     order by insert_time desc
     limit 1
) SELECT  my_mt.measurement_id,
          p.*
    from my_mt
    cross join jsonb_to_recordset(my_mt.data->'ports')
                as p(port_name text,
                     port_description text,
                     port_status_int int,
                     port_status text,
                     port_speed_int int,
                     ports_speed text);
```

Comment: So, explaining this a little in depth, if i'm not wrong: you're creating a temp table, and after that you use this temp table to do the cross join?

Comment: It's called a "common table expression" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), I don't think a temp table is involved, more like a view you define, but very good for performance if you need it more than once in the same query.